# Does $\big|\sum_{k=1}^na_k\big|\leq\sqrt{n}$ imply the convergence of $\sum_{1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Suppose $\big|\sum_{k=1}^na_k\,\big|\leq\sqrt{n}$ for all $n\geq 1$. Show that $\sum_{1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k}$ converges.

<strike>Summation by part doesn't help.</strike> ([**Added**: Thanks to the comments, I should have made my thought clear so that it would not cause confusion. It is not that "Summation by part doesn't help", but that "*I don't see* how 'summation by part' might work".]) I tried several convergence tests without any progress. The assumption gives an estimate for the Cesaro mean:
$$
\left|\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}{n}\right|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt n}.
$$
It seems that if I can get
$$
a_n\sim \left|\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}{n}\right|
$$
then things will be done since 
$$
\sum\frac{1}{\sqrt k \cdot k}
$$
converges. How shall I go on?

Comment: Wait, can you show summation by parts doesn't work? $|\sum_{j=1}^n a_k| \cdot (\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n})$ is order $1/n^{3/2}$.

Comment: Summation by parts was born for this.

Comment: This exercise is an EXCELLENT application of Abel's Summation method (aka summation by parts).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to all the comments above, I just found that I had been close to the answer. Summation by part would definitely work.

Let $A_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ and $b_k=\frac 1k$. Then 
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^na_kb_k&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}A_kb_k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}A_kb_{k+1}+A_nb_n\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}A_k\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)+A_n\frac{1}{n}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}A_k\frac{1}{k(k+1)}+A_n\frac{1}{n}
\end{align}
$$
The first term is convergent since
$$
\frac{A_k}{k(k+1)}\sim\frac{1}{k^{3/2}}.
$$
So is the second term:
$$
A_n/n\to 0.
$$